# Why does mongodb translate query to multiple singleton queries for replication?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

When a delete query is run on mongo primary node: `db.foo.remove({ price > 100 })` the query is translated into multiple singleton queries that are run on the secondaries:

```
db.foo.remove( { id: 383 } )
db.foo.remove( { id: 123 } )
db.foo.remove( { id: 233 } )
```

Why is this done? What advantage does this have over simply running the same queries on the secondaries again?

Comment: In a nutshell a secondary is not "guaranteed" to actually have "exactly" the same data as the primary. For instance, "if" it so happened that I sent a command to remove all greater than 100, then for some reason replication broke to the secondary and I inserted another value that was greater than 100 after that. When the secondary comes available it gets the two instructions but they "might" run in parallel. So unless I break that down to the atomic alterations, then I run the "possibility" of actually removing the new item I created on the primary from the secondary point of view.

Comment: That said. It's pretty broad to explain in full, and actually "off-topic" as *"What the database does under the hood"* is not really a programming topic, outside of learning how to write your own database. And we go back to too-broad etc.

Comment: @NeilLunn What you wrote seems a perfectly reasonable answer to me. I could have accepted that if you'd put it in as an answer